# realtime firebase database (0, _database.where) is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

ERROR

> ERROR  TypeError: (0, _database.where) is not a function. (In '(0, _database.where)('email', '==', email)', '(0, _database.where)' is undefined)

In here I am generating a uniqe perant in the database using uid and update some values in it, I am trying to do some filitration based on the email to know if users exist then update the values if not then generate a new user

```
import { ref, get, set, query, where} from 'firebase/database';
```

```
useEffect(() => {
  const writeToDatabase = () => {
    if (location && location.coords && UserDataFromGoogleAuth) {
      const usersRef = ref(database, 'users');
      const email = UserDataFromGoogleAuth.email;
      if (email) {
        const query = query(usersRef, where('email', '==', email));
        get(query).then((snapshot) => {
          const uuid = snapshot.exists() ? Object.keys(snapshot.val())[0] : uid();
          const userRef = ref(database, `/users/${uuid}`);
          const userData = {
            id: uuid,
            name: UserDataFromGoogleAuth.displayName,
            email: email,
            includedKids: 0,
            isSubscribed: false,
            long: location.coords.longitude,
            lat: location.coords.latitude,
            online: props.online,
            profilePicture: UserDataFromGoogleAuth.photoURL,
          };
          set(userRef, userData);
        }).catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
      }
    }
  };
  writeToDatabase();
}, [UserDataFromGoogleAuth, location, props.online]);
```

database structure:
Database> users> {uid foreach user}> {email}

Answer (score 1):

The `where` method is part of the Cloud Firestore API (`firebase/firestore`).

There is no direct equivalent in the Realtime Database API (`firebase/database`) that allows using a similar shorthand.

Instead, you invoke one of the many [`QueryConstraint`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.queryconstraint.md#queryconstraint_class) returning methods:
`endAt()`, `endBefore()`, `startAt()`, `startAfter()`, `limitToFirst()`, `limitToLast()`, `orderByChild()`, `orderByChild()`, `orderByKey()`, `orderByPriority()`, `orderByValue()` or `equalTo()`. Take a look at [`QueryConstraint`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.queryconstraint.md#queryconstraint_class) for links to the API reference for these methods and read over the documentation for [Realtime Database: Sorting and filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data).

The equivalent of

```
// firestore
const query = query(usersColRef, where('email', '==', email));
```

is

```
// database
const query = query(usersRef, orderByChild('email'), equalTo(email));
```